# How to improve my question: "What do I need to know to ensure that me and other people in the team are writing a quality software?"

Tags: discussion

This was the question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314767/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-ensure-that-me-and-other-people-in-the-team-are-writin?noredirect=1#comment665520_314767

> I have been told to ensure that me and everyone else in the team is
>   writing a quality software, and is following a proper process of
>   creating a  software.
>
> I have been told to ensure that our software does follow CMMI level 3 to some  extent.
>
> I want to know what I need to know and do about all this.
>
> Many years back I did read about the Waterfall model etc. where it is ? said    that we have to follow a sequence i.e. requirement
>   gathering, making design,    then writing code, and then testing. Here
>   I want to know what excatly am I   supposed to do w.r.t same?
>
> Making SRS is of course necessary at the start of the project, but I want to    know when (at which point of the project) should I
>   enforce class diagrams,    data flow diagrams, and flow charts?
>
> Are all these diagrams absolutely necessary all the time or are there some    factors on the basis of which I should decide whether I
>   should force them to   draw data flow diagrams and not flow charts, or
>   vice versa?
>
> We usually program in Qml and C++. We use Qml to build GUIs and it does not    have classes like C++. How should I ensure that
>   everyone is following some    design pattern rather then dumping all
>   the code in one file in QML? Is it    really practical for me to do
>   it? I guess that will require that I read    everyone's code,
>   understand what they are doing and ponder upon it for a    long 
>   time(?) Can I ensure that they do it someway?
>
> I have been told to checkout codes of different people working on different    projects from GIT and then verify using some tools as
>   Lint whether they are    writing proper code or not. What options
>   other than Lint are available for    the same?
>
> What method should I follow to tell other people that you haven't followed    this and that so you should correct it, and how do I keep
>   a tract of what    they have done or not done?
>
> Documentation: Ours is a culture where finishing work is important and    documenting that work is not considered that
>   important. Many senior people of    our company left without any
>   considerable documentation. I want to change    this. What should be
>   included in the average level documentation that I can force    every
>   team member to write? I cannot expect them to write extensive
>   documentation,    they won't do it, and    manager is simply not going
>   to force them.
>
> Please consider answering keeping QML and C++ in mind.

I will remove the sentence asking fr software recommendation.

I have been told:

> Too many questions is the main reason here, but several of these subquestions are themselves too broad or unspecified to be usefully answerable (and one is a tool recommendation which is off-topic). I'm not sure what part of this would be best to focus on since there's just so much stuff here,...

Which questions should I separate in independent threads, and how should I improve the questions?

Comment: You do realize how astoundingly broad your question is as a whole, and how even some of the sub-questions are themselves topics that are covered by complete books (or series of books)? To me, it looks like you need to do a bit more research on your own, including finding out exactly what is expected from you - looks like the scope of what you need to do is very broad, much too much if you need to be asking this question like this here.

Comment: It looks like you have some very specific questions there (each bullet point) within specific parameters I think you need to narrow down your question... maybe focus on one of your bullet points per question, and make the context for your question (CMMI Level 3, QML, C++) clear.

Answer (score 2):

Giving your post a quick once over again (I voted to close it first time round), I can see that there are at least 4 areas here:

- Development paradigm
- Tooling
- Checkout/code review policies
- Documentation

Even if you asked a question about each of these they would still be far too broad to be answered in a concise and readable way.

You do give some specifics (QML, C++) etc but this aside, it boils down to another "how should I program" type question which will (99 times out of a 100) get closed.

---

**Edit**

**Development paradigm**

- Waterfall
- Mini waterfall
- Agile
- Others

**Tooling**

- C++ best practices
- QML best practices

**Checkout/code review policies**

- VCS
- Static analysis tools
- Development standards
- Code review format
- CI

**Documentation**

- Use of a methodology
- Generated/outsourced documentation
- Agile documentation (minimum required)

Comment: So can you tell me with examples how I should narrow them down?

Comment: Not possible - still far too broad. To illustrate I'll break my list down one level further at which point I'll stop - as even here there is nowhere near enough detail to produce a cogent question producing a useful answer. Please bear in mind this is a Q & A site - not a free consultancy service.